# .htm file are recognized as template in django-sentry

Tags: django

Can anyone help me out. I have a problem in seeing the .htm files on browser.I have installed django-sentry for logging errors.
In settings.py if I change the DEBUG = true then I can see the contents of file opened in the browser but some of the images are not shown.
But when DEBUG =false then I get an error of 500.html displaying through sentry. The error I have seen from the sentry recording records in database file. And the error is :
ImproperlyConfigured
Internal Server Error: /media/Data/1/ahtm/noimgpreview.htm
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/var/www/django-trunk/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/var/www/django-trunk/django/views/static.py", line 41, in serve
return staticfiles_serve(request, path, document_root, show_indexes, insecure)

File "/var/www/django-trunk/django/contrib/staticfiles/views.py", line 45, in serve
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The view to serve static files can only "

ImproperlyConfigured: The view to serve static files can only be used if the DEBUG setting is True or the --insecure option of 'runserver' is used

But for any files like mp3,txt there contents are shown on the browser with both settings of DEBUG.How can I view .htm files on the browser.Only .htm files are not displayed other files with different formats are displayed properly.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The strange thing is that the others files are served, maybe, it's a cache problem? Read the [django.contrib.staticfiles](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/) documentation to learn [how to serve static files in production](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production), in particular the [collectstatic](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) management command.